# Conditional computation in spreadsheet considering the nearest value upwards

Tags: google-sheets

I need to perform spreadsheet computations, which consider values in a different column upwards; only till the specific value found. There are several issues, i see in the example google docs spreadsheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AtNTFloo47NbdERmUTBoQXlJRnBuOGpHNm50M2V6cVE&usp=sharing

- **(1)** Find difference of current row with the upward-nearest row satisfying certain condition (example: bold text in column F)
- **(2)** Find sum of all values between current row and the upward-nearest row satisfying certain condition (example: bold text in column E)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, these two formulae may be entered in row 1 and filled down as far as necessary:

`=IF(C1="Y";IFERROR(B1-FILTER(B$1:B1;ROW(B$1:B1)=LARGE(FILTER(ROW(B$1:B1);C$1:C1="Y");2)));IFERROR(1/0))`

`=IF(C1="Y";IFERROR(SUM(FILTER(D$1:D1;ROW(D$1:D1)>LARGE(FILTER(ROW(D$1:D1);C$1:C1="Y");2))));IFERROR(1/0))`

There would be an array output solution that would automatically populate the required cells down the column with a single formula, but it would be a very complex formula. Comment back if you had a need for such a solution.